# IE 11 DispatchEvent

Tags: javascript

We have a datepicker (in JavaScript) that has a section for checking IE 8 and older and other modern browsers.

```
if(-1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")){
obj_caller.target.fireEvent("onchange");
}
else {
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
obj_caller.target.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

It's working fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE8 and below but is failing in IE 11. What I need is a way to get the else part working in IE 11. I just cannot figure out what is failing and how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not sniff browsers! `if (document.createEvent)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that fireEvent shouldn't be used in newer IE versions.  Support for dispatchEvent was added in IE9. http://help.dottoro.com/ljrinokx.php

```
if(document.createEventObject) {
    obj_caller.target.fireEvent("onchange");
} else {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    obj_caller.target.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: The dispatchevent code is not working in IE 11 and I cannot figure out why. Is anything wrong with the code? I took out the whole if else loop and just tested in IE 11 with the dispatchevent code and it failed. Thanks.

Comment: Still not working. The code inside else is not executing in IE 11.

Comment: Works fine for me in all IE (including 11), Chrome, FF.  Does this fiddle work for you?  http://jsfiddle.net/ashleyglee/vsmac6xL/1/

Comment: The fiddle is working. Let me see if I can find out if something else is causing it to fail. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This code works on IE 6 and on IE 11. If you have any problems perhaps you may need a more specific event initialization with 
initDragEvent
initKeyEvent
initMessageEvent
initMouseEvent
initMutationEvent
initOverflowEvent
initTextEvent
initUIEvent

Comment: Have you found out what is going on? I'm having exactly the same problem.