# htmlEle.fireEvent("onclick", document.createEventObject()) doesn't work on IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, onclick, internet-explorer-11

Hi I have a click event associated with a image button. I am trying to fire the click event by `htmlEle.fireEvent("onclick", document.createEventObject())` but i get error **object doesn't support property or method 'createEventObject'** on IE 11. The click event works perfectly fine for IE 9. Is there a substitute for `createEventObject` that i can use for IE 11? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think `createEventObject` is not supported in IE 10+ ([source](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhlvomw.php)).

Try using something like this:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
myObject.target.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27643704/1678614).